# Fastest way to get the timezone from big data set of coordinates(a million coordinates or more)

Tags: r, timezone, coordinates, geospatial

What is the fastest way to get the local timezone in text of a large dataset of coordinates? My current method works fine, but the package I'm using "rundel/timezone" (which is simple and great for small sets) is quite slow for large sets.

Is there a faster way to accomplish the task reproduced below?:

```
  library(data.table)

#REPRODUCE DATA
  data <- data.table(latitude=sample(seq(47,52,by=0.001), 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                     longitude=sample(seq(8,23,by=0.001), 1000000, replace = TRUE))

  ###get timezone package via rundel/timezone
  if (!require("timezone")) devtools::install_github("rundel/timezone")
  library(timezone)


###CURRENT SLOW METHOD 

system.time(data[,timezone:=find_tz(longitude,latitude),])
       user  system elapsed 
     49.017  21.394  74.086
```

Comment: I happened to find the package called `lutz`. Have you checked it?

Comment: @jazzurro, no I had not seen that and for my purposes the method="fast" works great. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I think you want to check if everything is accurate. `tz_lookup_coords()`  can cause inaccuracies in timezones near boundaries away from populated ares.

Comment: Previous comment deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened to find the `lutz` package when I saw this question. It seems that this package is working for OP. I thought it'd be nice to leave a note here. In the package, there is a function called `tz_lookup_coords()`. You can set up method in two ways with this function. One is `method = "fast"` and the other is `method = "accurate"`. If you want speed, choose the first option. If you want accuracy, choose the second option. I leave the following result. You see a huge difference in time.

```
library(lutz) 
set.seed(111)
data <- data.table(latitude=sample(seq(47,52,by=0.001), 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                   longitude=sample(seq(8,23,by=0.001), 1000000, replace = TRUE))

system.time(data[, timezone := tz_lookup_coords(lat = latitude, lon = longitude, method = "fast")])

#user  system elapsed 
#6.46    3.42    9.92 

#Warning message:
#Using 'fast' method. This can cause inaccuracies in timezones
#near boundaries away from populated ares. Use the 'accurate'
#method if accuracy is more important than speed. 

system.time(data[, timezone := tz_lookup_coords(lat = latitude, lon = longitude, method = "accurate")])

#  user  system elapsed 
#154.44    0.18  154.93
```

Comment: From your comment this is exactly what I ended up with. It's about 10x faster than the previous. Didn't know lutz existed.

Comment: @NealBarsch I was surprised to see the difference. I am glad that this package helped you!

Comment: Thanks - I added both R libraries mentioned here to [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates).